# building unique list of select options from array in javascript?

Tags: javascript, arrays, html-select

I wrote this script,

```
<script>

const http = new XMLHttpRequest()
url = "http://192.168.0.2/hotspots";
window.onload = function(){
    var request = new XMLHttpRequest();

    request.onreadystatechange = function() {
        if (this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200) {
            result = eval(this.responseText)
            select = document.getElementById('access_points_select');
            for (var i = 0; i<=result.length; i++){
                var opt = document.createElement('option');
                opt.value = result[i];
                opt.innerHTML = result[i];
                select.appendChild(opt);
            }
        }
};

request.open('GET', url);
request.send();
}

</script>
</head>
<body>
<select name="access_points" id="access_points_select">
</select>
```

but because resource also returns duplicates i want to avoid duplicate entries into the select dropdown, how can I achieve this without creating unique array without creating another array then `result`.

Comment: Why "without creating another array" as a constraint, given how simple it would be if you could?

Comment: reason you are using `eval`?

Comment: Plenty of questions on getting uniques form an array

Comment: i was hoping if there is a way to query select options items thats why i said without other than `result`

Comment: you could add `if( i !== result.indexOf(result[i]) ) continue;` to the beginning of your for loop. Fairly common technique, [see here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1960473/get-all-unique-values-in-a-javascript-array-remove-duplicates)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If `eval(this.responseText)` returns an array you can use a [Set](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Set) to ensure there are no duplicates.

If you need to filter `undefined` you can do chain that on the end too:

```
 result = [...new Set(this.responseText)].filter(Boolean)
```

Comment: strangely i am getting an extra option with value undefined :(

Comment: that is messing up the output to each character as option in select.

Comment: what does responseText look like?

Comment: `[,t,h,i,s, ,a, ,w,o,r,d,] ` instead of 3 items I am getting 13 items in dropdown, i used `eval(this.responseText)` though which you forgot but that still gave `undefined`